# Hibernate `Session is closed` exception even the session is not closed

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I have a Coupons database, and using Hibernate I'm trying to get 5 rows.

This is the code:

```
public List<Coupon> getPage(int pageNum, boolean isActive) {
    session = factory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query;
    if(isActive) {
        query = session.createQuery("from Coupon where (NOW() < fadeoutDate)");
    } else {
        query = session.createQuery("from Coupon");
    }
    query.setFirstResult((pageNum - 1) * numCouponsPerPage);
    query.setMaxResults(numCouponsPerPage);
    List<Coupon> page = (List<Coupon>) query.list();
    closeSession();
    return page;
}
```

(numCouponsPerPage is a constant that equal 5)

When trying to get a page:

`List<Coupon> p = cm.getPage(dpage,active.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));` (dpage = 1, the second parameter return `false`),

I'm getting this error:

```
Dec 14, 2013 4:11:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/firstXDw] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /views/system/loadPage.jsp at line 30

27:     
28:     if (whatToLoad.equalsIgnoreCase("coupons")) {
29: 
30:         List<Coupon> p = cm.getPage(dpage,active.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
31:         for (Coupon c : p) {
32:             out.println("<tr>");
33:             out.println("<td>" + c.getId() + "</td>");


Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1768)
    at implementations.Coupons.getPage(Coupons.java:130)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.system.loadPage_jsp._jspService(loadPage_jsp.java:82)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why is exception `Session is closed` thrown? I open the session at the first line of the function..

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `private static SessionFactory sessionFactory =AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13492564/240078

Comment: @vikdor The error seems to happen _inside_ `getPage`, not at the for-each loop.

Comment: @Vikdor Still, I opened a session in the last line, how is it closed?

Comment: @user1798362, it's strange, what version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: @Vikdor I'm using hibernate 3.6.4